# Instagram API real-time limit

Tags: api, real-time, instagram

We would like to monitor a large area through the real-time API on Instagram. But unfortunately we quickly hit the max. 30 subscriptions roof. This will limit us to a 30 x 5 km radius area to monitor.

Any thoughts on how to monitor larger areas or have you heard of people getting a higher rate limit?

Comment: Ask Instagram. It's the limit made by Instagram.

Comment: Shivan obviously I am aware of that this is a limit from Instagram. I am asking for a workaround to the problem or any feedback on people who have seen Instrgram alter the limit for specific applications.

Comment: cluster of Instagram API accounts? Not sure if it violates Instagram API regulations.

Answer (score 2):

To monitor larger area, you can try to subscribe to location, instead of geography which is based on geolocation coordinates.

Steps could be as following:

1. easiest way to get the location, is to check its Foursquare id ([this one for Hong Kong Airport](https://foursquare.com/v/hong-kong-international-airport--hkg--%E9%A6%99%E6%B8%AF%E5%9C%8B%E9%9A%9B%E6%A9%9F%E5%A0%B4/4a7379d2f964a52088dc1fe3)),
2. map it to Instagram object_id (use [Instagram API Console](http://instagram.com/developer/api-console/)),
3. subscribe to this location using the object_id you just fetched
   (check Location Subscription [paragraph here](http://instagram.com/developer/realtime/)

**EDIT:** 
Regarding monitoring larger area - I'm using cluster of the accounts, and subscribing to set of locations, to not reach the limit. Works fine for couple months already.